# Symbol at (1) has no implicit type error in fortran

Tags: fortran

So, I am trying to simply define a variable and use it further in my code. Initially this was working but for some reason when I added more variables it stopped.

But, can someone explain how this can be a cause of error? variables a4, area, and dia are newly defined and I thought I can take care of them later, but skalHF was already there. And I am not sure what exactly I am missing, could also be a typo but I am not sure.

```
      subroutine UPrhoha_as33()
      implicit none
c     ------------------------------------------------------------------
      include 'xDatMetDefS_TPM.h'
c     ------------------------------------------------------------------
      include 'xMaPa_as26.h'
      include 'xDatB_as26.h'
      include 'eldata.h'
      include 'tdata.h'
c     ------------------------------------------------------------------
      integer i,tstep,j
      real*8 alpha,beta,k
      real*8 be
      real*8 facaT,qhL(3),qhI(3)
      real*8 ngradtheta(3),vorfac,norm 
      real*8 skalHF,area,a1,a2,a3,a4,dia
c     ------------------------------------------------------------------
c      tstep = dint(ttim/dt) 

      Tbr=thetamix-273.15
!      write(*,*)'Tbr= ',Tbr
c.............................................................

      rhodhI =0.0d0
      skalHF = 0.0d0
c..... area calculation from micro scale       
      a1=196.7638d0
      a2=-3.3443d0
      a3=0.3925d0
      a4=-1.2582d0
      dia=a4+(a1-a4)*dexp(-dexp(-a2*(nhI-a3)))
c.....convert to dimensional form      
      dia=2.84d0*dia
c..... area with units m2
      area=0.000001d0*3.14d0*dia**2.0d0/4.0d0
      
      norm = sqrt(Gradthetamix(1)**2.d0+Gradthetamix(2)**2.d0+
     &                     Gradthetamix(3)**2.d0)
      
      do i=1,3
      if (norm.eq.0.0d0) then
      ngradtheta(i) = 0.0d0
      else
      ngradtheta(i) = Gradthetamix(i)/norm
      end if

      qhL(i)=-0.5d0*Gradthetamix(i)
      qhI(i)=-2.3d0*Gradthetamix(i)

      skalHF = skalHF + (qhL(i)-qhI(i))*ngradtheta(i)

c      rhodhI =-facaT*skalHF/(335000d0)
      end do

      return 
      end
```

This is the subroutine and following are the errors that I get.

```
mate_as33.f:239:8:

       a4=-1.2582d0
        1
Error: Symbol ‘a4’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
mate_as33.f:244:10:

       area=0.000001d0*3.14d0*dia**2.0d0/4.0d0
          1
Error: Symbol ‘area’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
mate_as33.f:240:9:

       dia=a4+(a1-a4)*dexp(-dexp(-a2*(nhI-a3)))
         1
Error: Symbol ‘dia’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
mate_as33.f:234:12:

       skalHF = 0.0d0
            1
Error: Symbol ‘skalhf’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Comment: Please show more code, and copy-paste the full output of the compilation command.

Comment: I have added the relevant part of the subroutine. The entire code is too many line and part of  a software, so can't really give a reproducible example. Sorry

Comment: Does the word `subroutine` start in column 1 or 7? same for `return end` which is anyway a bit strange that it is on one line.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I think the copy and paste messed them up. They are all on column 7 with return and end on separate lines. I have edited the original question now.

Comment: The compiler complains that you did not declare some of the variables you used. Because you are using `implicit none`, you have to declare all variables. Please note that the code example is not complete, because we do not see the include files.

Comment: Update, I changed a1,a2,a3,a4 and dia to p1,p2,p3,p4 and diameter and somehow it worked. So, I guess the variable names were clashing from somewhere else, although I don't see that. Thanks for your comments tho.